# How can I check if selected row has certain contact title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using the sample [index.cshtml](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/index) found on the Kendo UI demos for ASP.NET MVC, how can I check if the row I selected has certain contact title?

E.g. if I select a row and I want to see if that row contains contact title 'Sales Representative'? How can I do this in javaScript?

I understand that I can bind an event to the grid but I'm not sure how to get the specific row value/id and check if the contact title is sales representative?

Here's the code snippet:

```
<div id="clientsDb">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Width(140);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ContactTitle).Width(190);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(110);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid"))
        )
    )
</div>

<style>
    #clientsDb {
        width: 952px;
        height: 396px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        padding: 51px 4px 0 4px;
        background: url('@Url.Content("~/content/web/grid/clientsDb.png")') no-repeat 0 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the grid an Id and use the following:

Add this to your grid:

```
.Events(events => events.Change("gridClick"))
```

then use this function:

```
function gridClick(){
    var grid = $("#gridIdHere").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedRow = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    if(selectedRow.contactTitle == "Sales Representative"){
        ..Do stuff here
    }
}
```

selectedRow will contain all of the fields in your model.

Comment: I have access to all the fields in my model already. I want to do something like this but properly:  this.events.sender._data[i].ContactTitle. I want to get the Contact Title but for that specific row. How do I do that?

Comment: if(selectedRow.ContactTitle == "Sales Representative") - selectedRow will contain the selected item from your grid.  Maybe I still don't understand the full problem.

Comment: I am getting grid.select() is not a function

Comment: Did you give your grid an id?

Comment: Yes, my grid returns an object with info.

Comment: Okay so I fixed the issue with the grid but now it says selectedRow is undefined

Comment: For this part: var selectedRow = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

Comment: Did you add the line declaring selected row?  (var selectedRow = ...)